# Selenium IDE - Verify random generated email

Tags: email, selenium, random, ide, verify

I want to use this below code to randomize an email address creation - but on my website I have another "type" field which requires me to verify this email address afterwards, so it needs to type in that specific generated address to make it work - how can I do that easily ?

```
    <tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>Math.round (Math.random() * 1357)</td>
    <td>random</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>selenium${random}@domain.com</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. What is stopping you from just entering the same email into the verification field? You still have the right value stored in `random`...

Comment: You're absolutely right (I'm a rookie hehe) - got it to work, thanks for input.

Comment: If you did, please post your solution as an answer and accept it, so anyone in the future would be able to solve the same problem, too. Or delete the question.

Comment: I used the same code as above and then just added this: selenium${random}@domain.com in the value field of the verify address.

Comment: Did you get a satisfactory answer from anyone to accept, or is there still issues with the suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to use a variable that does your calculation to a random number.  Place that variable in the selenium test so it has the same number.

```
var Random = Math.round (Math.random() * 1357);
```

Then use this variable in the page and Selenium test.